# S3 Select with dots in csv header name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have CSV file in AWS S3 as following:

```
"m.deviceid";"m.eventtype"
"TestDevice";"TestEvent"
```

If I use S3 select as follows:
Expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM S3Object s 
WHERE s.\"m.eventtype\" LIKE \"TestEvent\"'
```

I will receive message ""Some headers in the query are missing from the file. Please check the file and try again."

S3 Select documentation does not clearly indicate that are there are dots in CSV headers supported?

Answer (score 0):

These work OK:

```
select * from s3object s where s."m.eventtype" = 'TestEvent'

select * from s3object s where s."m.eventtype" like '%Test%'
```

Comment: Are you still having a problem, or did this fix it for you?